# How to check all the folder inside files and subfolder inside files have particular string present

Tags: python, operating-system

- I have folders and files present
- I have subfolders and files also
- I need to search a particular string present also in same file other string not present
- all the files are in `.txt`
- I need to check files which string `20210624` is present inside the file and string `20210625` not in the files
- My output return the file names

```
import os
match_str = ['20210624']
not_match_str =  ['20210625']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".txt")):
             ## search files with match_str `20210624`  and not_match_str `20210625`
```

Can i use using `import walk`

Comment: You have to read each file after you get the file. Then you can check if number is present in the file

Comment: @PCM Please refrain from making nonsense edits like this. Adding generic tags like [tag:operating-system] or [tag:algorithm] or [tag:list] does not help anyone make more sense of these questions; most of your proposed edits have been on awful questions which could perhaps have been made less awful; but you just decided to propose adding a tag which provided no actual additional value.

Comment: Added it in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `recursive` keyword argument in the [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) method to `True` for the program to search recursively through the files of the folders, subfolders, etc.

```
from glob import glob

path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop'
for file in glob(path + '\\**\\*.txt', recursive=True):
    with open(file) as f:
        text = f.read()
        if '20210624'  in text and '20210625' not in text:
            print(file)
```

If you don't want to entire path of the files to be printed; only the filenames, then:

```
from glob import glob

path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop'
for file in glob(path + '\\**\\*.txt', recursive=True):
    with open(file) as f:
        text = f.read()
        if '20210624'  in text and '20210625' not in text:
            print(file.split('\\')[-1])
```

---

In order to use the [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) method, you can use the [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method *(as you have done in your post)* like so:

```
import os

for path, _, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(path, file)) as f:
                text = f.read()
                if '20210624'  in text and '20210625' not in text:
                    print(file)
```

And to search within a maximum level of subdirectories:

```
import os

levels = 2
root = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop'
total = root.count('\\') + levels

for path, _, files in os.walk(root):
    if path.count('\\') > total:
        break
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            print(os.path.join(path, file))
```

Comment: is there any i can search for 2 level of subfolders only

Comment: @sim Yes, I added it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `pathlib` and [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob).

```py
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path(path)
maybe_valids = list(path.glob("*20210624*.txt"))
valids = [elem for elem in maybe_valids if "20210625" not in elem.name]
print(valids)
```

`maybe_valids` list is created taking every element that contains "20210624" and ends with .txt, while `valids` are the ones that doesn't contain "20210625".

Comment: I think the OP wanted to find the string inside the file, not the filename.

Comment: Quoting OP, "My output return the file names", so I think that's the desired behaviour

Comment: But then the previous point by OP, "I need to check... present inside the file...", makes the question rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Continue from here -

```
if name.endswith((".txt")):
   f = file.read(name,mode='r')
   a = f.read()
   if match_str[0] in f.read():
      # Number is present
```

You can use for loops for reading too if you have more than one match_str.
Similarly, you can use `not in` keyword to check for not_match_str

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file names with several simple shell commands:

```sh
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -l "20210624" | xargs grep -L "20210625"
```